# Сравнение нескольких объектов с переменной python

Tags: python, if

Ксть одна переменная message и несколько значений нужно сравнить их. Я пробовал через if но не получалось

```
if message == ('a','b','c') : 
    print('right') 
else:
    print('false')
```

Пробовал так как выше но не получалось.

Comment: Что значит "сравнить их"? Проверить, что значение `message` равно одному из элементов кортежа?

Comment: Sergey,да что-бы если значение равно выполнялось действие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if message in ('a','b','c'):
    print('right')
else:
    print('false')
```

Comment: Спасибо.Все заработало

Comment: @EgorShutyaev [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).